How to disable anonymous user in spring security 6.1+
"
I cannot disable anonymous users (I must use JWT, and this token is generated from an SSO using Spring Security 4.x).
Please help me, thank you everyone.
I am using the following java 17, spring security 6+, libraries:
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    </dependency>

My code, Security config class, When debugging during program startup, it has already entered here:
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfigBase {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)  // Tắt CSRF
                .anonymous(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v0.1/security/test").authenticated()  // Endpoint /test yêu cầu xác thực
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()  // Tất cả các endpoint khác đều yêu cầu xác thực
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter()))  // Xử lý JWT
                )
                .exceptionHandling(exceptions -> exceptions
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))  // Trả về 401 nếu không có auth
                );
        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        String secretKey = "key";  // Đảm bảo key chính xác
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256")).build();
    }

    private JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        JwtAuthenticationConverter converter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        converter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(new CustomJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(userService));
        return converter;
    }
}

and  this is customer Jwt Granted class:
import com.aiassistant.common.service.UserService;
import com.grooo.jpa.model.exception.CustomException;
import exception.CustomExceptionEnum;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CustomJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {

    private final UserService userService;

    public CustomJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt jwt) {
        // Lấy thông tin người dùng qua API
        try {
            UserDetails userDetails = userService.loadUserByUsername();
        // Trích xuất quyền từ UserDetails
        return userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
            .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getAuthority()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new CustomException(CustomExceptionEnum.SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}


and this is console error:
2024-12-06 17:11:27,333 DEBUG [http-nio-8085-exec-5] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy: doFilterInternal Securing GET /api/v0.1/security/test
2024-12-06 17:11:27,333 DEBUG [http-nio-8085-exec-5] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy: lambda$doFilterInternal$3 Secured GET /api/v0.1/security/test
2024-12-06 17:11:27,335 DEBUG [http-nio-8085-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter: defaultWithAnonymous Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext

I try using:
.anonymous(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)

but not working
